# Telerik RadGrid scrollbar is offsetting the columns

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid

I have a page with anywhere between 1 and 6 dynamically built iframes containing RadGrids in two columns on the page. I've managed to get a column by the name Document Number to line up in all of them, however if one of them contains more data then the space allowed it will scroll. This is expected and correct.

My issue is when the scrollbar does show it pushes all my columns left just a smidge in that grid, and now it's out of sync with the other grids. I've added a small column which I can dynamically display to push the other grids' columns to match, I just need to be able to detect/determine if a scroll bar is actually being displayed.

I found an [old telerik post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/determine-if-vertical-scrollbar-is-visible) that suggests I use the scroll height vs the overflow height and if scroll height is larger then we know there's a scroll bar being displayed. My attempts to use the supplied javascript have shown me that the post is outdated and that GridDataDiv no longer exists.

Is there a new/updated way to detect the presence of a scrollbar? Alternatively, is there a better way to have my document number columns even regardless of scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the grid's client width and the scroll area width of the grid data:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("RadGrid1"),
    scrollArea = document.getElementById("RadGrid1_GridData");

// ex. 171 (note no units included)
alert("grid.clientHeight: " + grid.clientHeight);

// ex. 300px (note the "px" units are included)
alert("scrollArea.style.height: " + scrollArea.style.height);

// Is the verticle scroll bar visible?
var vertIsVis = scrollArea.style.height.replace("px", "") > grid.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Awesome. I will attempt this when the page I'm working on is no longer being tested. haha. Thank you!

Comment: Ever get a chance to try this out?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. They keep moving my projects around. I'm tempted to try it on a weekend.